# How is the surface tension of water related to transpiration?

Tags: membrane-transport

My textbook mentions the following :

**• Surface Tension – water molecules are attracted to each other in
the liquid phase more than water in the gas phase.**

I can't understand how that would help in transpiration.

Comment: I think the question needs more clarity: the quote given does not fully define surface tension - it is merely a correct statement about difference between a liquid and a gas. It is also not clear why the author thinks that it plays a role in transpiration.

Comment: My textbook actually mentions three things. Cohesion, adhesion and surface tension. The first two, I can understand is to maintain the continuous stream of water but I can't understand the role of surface tension.

Comment: surface tension plays a role in liquid moving up the pores, and also in gorming droplets on the skin, but it is hard say more without knowing the context.

Comment: Is the textbook abour plants? Surface tension is inmortant in plant laefs.

Answer (score 0):

Complete reference:

> ***The transpiration driven ascent of xylem sap** depends mainly on the
> following physical properties of water:*

> *• Cohesion – mutual attraction between water molecules.*

> *• Adhesion – attraction of water molecules to polar surfaces (such
> as the surface of tracheary elements).*

> *• Surface Tension – water molecules are attracted to each other in
> the liquid phase more than to water in the gas phase.*

The ascent of xylem sap is aided by surface tension since it allows the water to hold together and create a continuous column of water. Otherwise, the capillarity would be affected (the water column could 'collapse' under it's own weight, for example) and plants would be unable to conduct water via the xylem. Surface tension, cohesion and adhesion are common to capillarity occurring outside of living systems as well.

Recommended read:  https://www.usgs.gov/special-topic/water-science-school/science/capillary-action-and-water?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects